# Ignoring xml elements using XmlParser

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5

I am trying to parse XML to array using orchestra which is a XML Document Parser package for Laravel. I have managed to parse Title node using the code below. Challenge that I am having is to parse this element James Bond, which will result in giving me the value of James Bond. Below is test.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Requisition>
<Title>Business Analyst</Title>    
<CustomInfo>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT1"></Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT2"></Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT3">0</Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT4">Brackens</Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_REQ_ACTOR_NAME" code="JAMES_BOND">James Bond</Field> //Node I trying to parse/print
<Field fldCode="FLD_REQ_ACTOR_NAME_COMP" code="AAX">aaX</Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_REQ_ACTOR_NAME_DIV" code="RESOURCING_ARIZONA">Resourcing Arizona</Field>      
</CustomInfo>
</Requisition>
</ExportData>
```

and here is controller code were im parsing the test.xml file

```
public function index()
{

$xml = XmlParser::load('/path/to/my/test.xml');
$ExportData = $xml->parse([
'Title' => ['uses' => 'ExportData.Requisition.Title'],
'Actor Name' => ['uses' => 'ExportData.Requisition.CustomInfo.Field::fldCode'],
]);
echo '<pre>'; print_r ($ExportData); echo '</pre>';
```

and this is the result i get when i print the array

```
[Title] => Business Analyst
[Actor Name] => FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT1
```

Does anyone have an idea on how i can ignore these elements below using php and xmlParser

```
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT1"></Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT2"></Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT3">0</Field>
<Field fldCode="FLD_PF_CUSTOM_REQ_TEXT4">Brackens</Field>
```

Comment: check those field-code attributes for `FLD_REQ_ACTOR_NAME`. Either by iterating and doing a `if (...)` or by a `xpath` query. I have no idea on how to do this with the technology you require.

Comment: in the very tiny doc, they mention a property-method. Maybe play around with that.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand which property-method you are referring to. Do you mind giving an example?

Comment: see V3.2.0 third bullet: https://github.com/orchestral/parser/blob/master/docs/changes.md